# Cut string at a certain character

Tags: c

Im trying to make a function which cuts and prints/does something with parts of a string.

Say i have this string:

```
"strings.no.header"
```

And i would like to split it up so it prints something like this:

```
strings
no
header
```

Here is my lousy attempt, where i am first able to (without the else statement) print out "strings". My idea was to make the function recursive so it prints and removes the first part before ".", and then does the same with the rest of the string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void cut(char string[]);

int main() {
  char string[] = "strings.no.header";
  cut(string);
}

void cut(char string[]) {
  char *toString = malloc(sizeof(char));
  int len = strlen(string);

  for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    int count = 0;
    if(string[i] != '.') {
      toString[i] = string[i];
    } else if(string[i] == '.') {
      char *tmp = malloc(sizeof(char));
      tmp = string + i;
      cut(tmp);
    }
  }
  printf("%s", toString);
}
```

Would be grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Please understand that `char *toString = malloc(sizeof(char));` allocates *one byte* of memory so indexing the pointer is useless. Moreover, `char *tmp = malloc(sizeof(char)); tmp = string + i;` is similar, but immediately overwrites the pointer to memory you have allocated.

Comment: I mean you want the strtok function from string.h. see this page: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/
especially the example at the bottom.

Comment: fix your approach like [this](https://ideone.com/yVSznn)

Comment: @SherylHohman: Why do you want to invoke undefined behaviour for modifying an immutable character sequence?

Comment: @Olaf Not what I meant, but you're right, I used imprecise language.  I deleted said comment, as it really wasn't useful or helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I have an idea:

check this web page: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Strings

use strchr to find '.'then, once you know the position, copy the characters in other string, remember that you already know where the '.' appears, so you know exactly what to copy.

Comment: Can you please show the code that implements your idea?

Answer (score 1):

[Strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) is your friend. No need to reinvent the wheel.

```
void cut (const char* str){
  char * pch;
  pch = strtok (str,".");
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, ".");
  }
}
```

The code is just a quick edit of the sample from the link.

Answer (score 1):

A solution with [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void cut(char string[]);

int main()
{

  char string[] = "strings.no.header";
  cut(string);

}


void cut(char string[])
{
    char *pch;
    pch = strtok (string, ".");
    while (pch != NULL)
    {
        printf ("%s\n",pch);
        pch = strtok (NULL, ".");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, for something like this, `strtok` will give you what you need. A word of warning, **this function will wreck your string**, so it is always advisable to make a copy first.

Basically, what `strtok` does is replace all characters in the string that match the second argument of `strtok` and replace them with the `'\0'` character. The function then returns the pointer to the first "token". Each subsequent call to `strtok` will return the pointer to the next token. [Here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm) is a basic tutorial.

To keep it simple, I kept all the code in the `main`. You can now use this technique to implement the logic that suits your particular problem.

```
int main()
{
    char string[] = "strings.no.header";
    char buffer[50] = { 0 };//make sure big enough
    char* token = NULL;
    char* nextToken = NULL;

    //want to make a copy because strtok will wreck the string
    strcpy(buffer, string);

    token = strtok_s(buffer, ".", &nextToken);
    while (token)
    {
        printf("%s\n", token);//or do whatever you like.
        token = strtok_s(NULL, ".", &nextToken);//pass NULL on subsequent calls
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

*You may find this interesting that:*
After the first call of `token = strtok_s(buffer, ".", &nextToken);`,
`buffer` now contains: `"strings\0no.header"`.

After the second call, 
`buffer` now contains: `"strings\0no\0header"`.

This is the reason why you want to make a copy of the original string before using `strtok`. If you do not care about the original `string`, it is ok to use it.

Comment: @chfxin, you are welcome! If your problem was solved, please consider accepting the answer that most helped you. This will also help future users. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358870/7159784)